# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} k^{1/n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} k^{1/n}$ converge when $k<1$ ??? How to show whether it does or does not then? Integral test or comparison test with $k^n$ does not seem to work.

Comment: Does $k^{1/n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: It does not seem to. I think the terms converge to 1, but I ain't sure about their sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\displaystyle \sum a_n$ converges, [it is necessary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test) that $a_n \rightarrow 0$.  What is $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1/n$?  Given that $k^x$ is continuous, what is $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} k^{1/n}$?

Comment: It is 1. So the sum diverges?

Comment: Indeed @RedFlag, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test

Comment: Also a good thing I can note is that this diverges not only for $k<1$, but for all real values of k except 0

Comment: Yep, the value for $k$ is pretty irrelevant, except if we had $k = 0$.

Comment: Edited my previous comment to exclude $k=0$ :)